# ServiceStack JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString won't work with UTF-8 strings

Tags: php, .net, utf-8, xamarin.ios, servicestack

I need to support UTF-8 in my MonoTouch iPhone app and have just updated all my server PHP scripts to be encoded in UTF-8 instead of ANSI.

This change has broken my client code and an exception is thrown in ServiceStack when trying to serialize the returned string from the PHP scripts.

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (webResponse.GetResponseStream (), Encoding.UTF8))
{
    string responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();

    myDto = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString (responseString, dtoType);
}

Exception: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type definitions should start with a '{', expecting serialized type 'UserGamesDTO', got string starting with: ﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿{"uc":"0","gma":[{"gid":"838","ui
```

The exception is complaining that the string doesn't start with a '{' when it clearly does, so does this mean ServiceStack can't work with UTF-8 strings, or do I need to set something?

Thanks.

Comment: What is `webResponse.ContentEncoding` ?

Comment: Hi I4V, the ContentEncoding is empty. So does that mean I have to specify UTF-8 in my php scripts? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you consider byte order mark (BOM) charecter, this is a Unicode charecter that is not shown in text editors.
maybe you should get rid of it.

Comment: This looks like the issue, thanks Amir. 

I examined the byte stream and found it starts with the bytes 239, 187 & 191, which is the BOM for UTF-8.

I opened up my PHP files in Notepad++ and converted them to UTF-8 (without BOM) and it's working again now.

Answer (score 0):

please use json.net library

```
var cfg = new ConfigFile();
cfg.xxx = xxx;
....
var str = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cfg);


var str = File.ReadAllText (filename, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
if (! String.IsNullOrEmpty (str)) {
    var cfg = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConfigFile> (str);
}
```

Comment: I did look into using Newtonsoft but ServiceStack was easier to get working with MonoTouch. Apart from this issue it's been very good.